# Point a domain to google cloud

Tags: g-suite, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have setup Google Cloud Debian Instance and has this IP: "104.197.233.183".

I setup Google DNS as:

[image: google cloud dns]

Domain name server for 11tips.com at the registar looks like this:

[image: NS records for a domain]

Virtual host conf in the server looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@11tips.com
  ServerName 11tips.com
  ServerAlias www.11tips.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

And last, /etc/hosts looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost 11tips.com www.11tips.com
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
10.128.0.4 lamp-1-vm.c.codefight-cms.internal lamp-1-vm  # Added by Google
```

Now when I go to 11tips.com, it doesn't load a site. What am I missing here. I am not good with servers, so hopefully someone can help me point my domain to Google Cloud.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was creating / deleting dns few times as I didn't know what I was doing.

When I entered NS record to my domain, google dns was:

`ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com`

But as I deleted and created again, c1 changed to d1 and I didn't notice that.

`ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com`

Once I fixed that, site started loading.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was that you might need to create a glue record at the registrar for the NS, but you have them defined as googledomain.com servers.
https://wiki.gandi.net/en/glossary/glue-record

The DNS Tools check says something about your SOA record:
[http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport|type=domain&&value=11tips.com](http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport%7Ctype=domain&&value=11tips.com)

Like the registrar page says, your nameservers need to resolve your domain:  if they don't, something is misconfiguring on the hosting side (I haven't tried using Google Cloud hosting DNS)